# How do I project points such as to extend a curve?

Tags: algorithms

Given a roughly drawn line (i.e. a squiggle) consisting of, say a few dozen points, how do I extend the line in keeping with the last few points of the line, i.e. if the line was curving downwards at a rate how do I extend that behaviour by a few points?

I'm imagining there might be something along the lines of: given an array of points, taking the last 3 or 4 points as arguments, this function will calculate the next 3 or 4 points as if the curving trend had continued in the same way?

Also, I'm a mathematical amateur and ideally need something I can readily convert into code. Any tips on tags would be helpful too because this is my first post and others will probably be in a similar category.

Answer (score 1):

A key word to look up might be "splines".

Comment: Bit to broad a keyword.  I'm thinking I'm a database programmer that's trying to find some inroads into mathematical graphics programming (a big wide gulf)

Comment: Too broad? Try "cubic splines".